# Cinnamon doesn't work under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon

So, yesterday I finished upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. The first thing that I noticed is that when I want to log in using Cinnamon, the screen just freezes for a few seconds, turns black and then returns me to the login screen. I already tried reinstalling Cinnamon, and it didn't work. Does anyone know how can I fix this? (and yes, I know that Linux Mint is a thing, but I don't want to replace my current installation of Ubuntu).

Comment: How did you installed Cinnamon?

Comment: @N0rbert I used `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment`

Comment: Nevermind, turns out that Cinnamon now works after I reinstalled Ubuntu -- and it works better than before!